# How does Lindeberg CLT imply classicial CLT?

Tags: probability-theory

For a sequence of zero-mean $\sigma^2$-variance IID random variables $X_1, \dots,$ the Linderberg condition is applied this way:
$\forall \epsilon >0$, as $n$ goes to $\infty$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n E(\frac{|X_i|^2}{n\sigma^2} \times I_{|X_i| > \epsilon \sqrt{n}\sigma}) \to 0$$
which is by IID
$$E(\frac{|X_1|^2}{\sigma^2} \times I_{|X_1| > \epsilon \sqrt{n}\sigma}) \to 0$$
same as
$$E(|X_1|^2 \times I_{|X_1| > \epsilon \sqrt{n}}) \to 0$$
If I am all correct in the process, how is the last one true? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every nonnegative random variable $Z$, the property that $E[Z\,\mathbf 1_{Z\geqslant z}]\to0$ when $z\to\infty$ is equivalent to $Z$ being integrable. (Proof: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.)

**Edit:** To prove that if $Z$ is integrable then $E[Z\,\mathbf 1_{Z\geqslant z}]\to0$, consider $Z_n=Z\,\mathbf 1_{Z\geqslant n}$. Note that $Z_n\to0$ almost surely and that $Z_n\leqslant Z$ with $Z$ integrable hence all the pieces to apply Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem are in place.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your hint. One direction is now proven if I am correct. Now I am stuck at how to prove the other direction? That is, given $Z$ is integrable, how shall I prove $E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$?

Comment: See Edit. Your proof should be complete by now.