# An equivalent condition for integrability of a measurable function?

Tags: probability-theory

[Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/352129/3616) said that for any nonnegative random variable $Z$, $E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ is equivalent to $Z$ being integrable, i.e. $E Z < \infty$.

Here is my proof for one direction,
$$
E Z = E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) + E (Z \times I_{Z \leq z}).
$$
Given $E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$, $\forall \epsilon_1>0$, there exists $z_1 >0$ such that $E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) < \epsilon$ for all $z> z_1$.
$E (Z \times I_{Z \leq z}) \leq z \times P(Z \leq z)$.
So $$
E Z = E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) + E (Z \times I_{Z \leq z}) \leq \epsilon_1 + z \times P(Z \leq z) < \infty.
$$

Now I am stuck at how to prove the other direction? That is, given $Z$ is integrable, how shall I prove $E (Z \times I_{Z > z}) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$?

Comment: You really shouldn't use $\times$ to denote pointwise multiplication... Using $I$ to denote the characteristic function is rather non-standard, too. In fact, I could not understand what you were talking about until I read the post by Did you linked.

Comment: @tomasz: sorry about that. I don't know how to write properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Z\cdot I_{Z>n}\le Z$ for all $n=1$, $2$, $\dots$, and $Z\cdot I_{Z>n}\to 0$ pointwise as $n\to\infty$, so, by the dominated convergence theorem, ${\Bbb E}(Z\cdot I_{Z>n})\to {\Bbb E}(0)=0.$  If you wish to take the limit as $z$ goes to infinity in $\Bbb R$, it follows from the preceding that $\lim_{z\to\infty} {\Bbb E}(Z\cdot I_{Z>z})=0$ because ${\Bbb E}(Z\cdot I_{Z>z})\le {\Bbb E}(Z\cdot I_{Z>\lfloor z\rfloor}).$

Comment: Thanks! Is my proof of the other direction in my post correct?

Comment: The idea is correct.  There's an $\epsilon$ where there should be an $\epsilon_1$, and it's not clear what value of $z$ you eventually end up using (any finite $z>z_1$ would work.)